# Performance: ViewGroup with Children VS. custom drawn View

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls, android-view, android-custom-view

I'm developing an App with lot's of custom views and ran into performance issues with a quite complex one of them. The time they take for measuring and drawing is to high (>= 30ms typical). To give some more details: It's a custom `ViewGroup` (extending `RelativeLayout`) with custom Views (extending `RelativeLayout` although) as it's children.

So I'm it came across my mind what might be the better/quicker approach for getting rid of this performance problems: Optimize the children and layouts or switch to a completely custom drawn view (lines, rectangles and stuff like these)?

Do any of you have experience in one or another? Or even some done some benchmarks and is willing to share them?

Comment: Have you found the answer ?
I need to make a decision as well. In my case there are a lot of bitmaps on the screen. They are moving and rotating. 
Should I make ViewGroup with ImageViews, and call requestLayout() every update.
Or is it better to make CustomView, and draw all these bitmaps on canvas, and call invalidate() every update?

Comment: I've chosen a custom View, doing measuring and drawing myself.In my case it was the better - or to be precise the more performant - way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple approach would be to work on simplifying and flattening the current view hierarchy and maybe you'll be able to make the measuring and drawing process much cheaper(or decent at least). You didn't posted a layout so there isn't something specific to say, I've seen you mentioned `RelativeLayouts` in `RelativeLayouts`, maybe you could remove one and move the views up one level(even with the expense of adding other helper views), every level counts(especially with nesting `RelativeLayouts`). You probably know already but the `merge` and `include` tags in layouts could prove quite useful.

`RelativeLayout` being in the standard SDK was built as a general widget so it most likely can't achieve the performance of a custom designed layout. It would make much more sense to make your current layouts extending `RelativeLayout` to extend `ViewGroup` and implement the measuring and layout of children manually especially as you probably know the use case scenarios in your apps(for example a `RelativeLayout` always needs to handle all the size constraint cases it could be in, your custom layout on the other hand could handle this much faster if you know that the custom view will have a certain size).

Related to a *completely custom drawn view*, it's an option but it depends on the complexity of your layout.

> Or even some done some benchmarks and is willing to share them?

I don't see how various view benchmarks(which most likely will not apply to your specific situation) will help.